# How long in years the artist was in the band for all artists who are or ever have been in bands

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For the artists currently in bands, the value is null. How can I calculate how long they have been in the band if the value is null using mySQL?

I was thinking of doing something like this, which only works for artists who have left a band.

```
truncate(datediff(m.leave_date, m.joined_date)/365, 0)
```

Comment: Sample table data would really help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done SQL for a while so please bear with me.

Basically, you want to coalesce your leave date to "now" if it's null (current member).  See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp

```
truncate(datediff( 
    ifnull(m.leave_date, now()),
    m.joined_date)/365, 0)
```